# Cant connect to docker - This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: python, json, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am learning how to use docker, kafka, and python.

I am trying to use python to read json files and send them to kafka.

I was able to have the system running but i cant seem to be able to see the messages sent.

i keep on getting the same errors whether in VM using ubuntu or even in windows with Docker Desktop.

i created several files:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://:9092"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      LOG4J_CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar

volumes:
  kafka-data:
```

kafka_consumer.py

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer("streaming", bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092", group_id="my-group", auto_offset_reset="earliest")

for message in consumer:
    print(f"Received message: {message.value.decode()}")

consumer.close()
```

kafka_producer.py

```
import json
import os

for filename in ["A.json", "B.json", "C.json", "D.json"]:
    print(f"Reading file: {filename}")
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            try:
                data = json.load(f)
                print(f"Successfully loaded JSON from {filename}")
                for message in data:
                    print(f"Sending message: {message}")
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print(f"Error loading JSON from {filename}: {e}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"File {filename} not found.")
```

here's an example of the data to be pulled from the .json files

{"time":"12:05:09.000 AM","customer":"Zane Lalo","action":"shut down","device":"HP Laptop"},

I tried everything, tried erasing the docker files. installing it in ubuntu. windows.

i was able to get it running in ubuntu. but cant get see the messages being consumed.

[~]$ kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic streaming

> 

nothing happens always stuck at this stage.

also when i tried it on windows. i can not access the localhost i get the following message all the time:

This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

despite that the docker is running properly.

I really don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: When you say "access the localhost", which of the three localhosts in the question are you using, and how?  Your producer code doesn't seem to be connecting to Kafka at all, and I don't think `kafka-console-producer` actually writes anything to its stdout (you'd type or paste these messages into its stdin).  It's possible that all of the connectivity is correct but nothing is actually sending a message.

Comment: Your Python producer script should maybe import the KafkaProducer and use it to produce something? Otherwise, the console producer isn't stuck, you need to type something in there to produce

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `kafka_producer.py` file isn't connecting to kafka.. and therefore isn't producing anything.

e.g. something like this but with your data...

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import time

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

for i in range(10):
    message = f"Message {i}"
    print(f"Sending: {message}")
    producer.send('streaming', value=message.encode())
    time.sleep(1)

producer.close()
```